# How can I download a file via background.js automatic in chrome extension v3?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

When the url changed I want to download the latest url to local. In v2 it is possiable, But in v3 I can't modify the dom via background.js.
does there have a method to do it?

below is my v2 code:

background.js:

```
var urlList = ["https://www.google.com/"]
var lastUrl = ""

function download(filename, text) {
    var element = document.createElement('a');
    element.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(text));
    element.setAttribute('download', filename);

    element.style.display = 'none';
    document.body.appendChild(element);

    element.click();

    document.body.removeChild(element);
}

chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(
    function (tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
        if(lastUrl==tab.url){
            return
        }
        lastUrl=tab.url
        for (let i = 0; i < urlList.length; ++i) {
            if (tab.url.indexOf(urlList[i]) > -1) {                                
                download('url.txt', tab.url);
                return
            }
        }

    }
)
```

hello.html:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello Extensions</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "My test extension",
  "version": "1",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "background": {
    "scripts":["background.js"]
  },
  "permissions": [
    "tabs"
  ]
}
```

I hope above code can working at v3.

Comment: @NorioYamamoto Hi, Thanks for the comment, Hi, Thanks for the viedo, But I have a question. When I tried to sendMessage like below code shows, 
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(async (tab) => {
  await chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ type: "pause", offscreen: true });
});
it reprot error: 3 worker.js:53 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.

does there have any solutions?Thank you!!

Comment: Why don't you just use [chrome.downloads.download](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/downloads/#method-download)?

Comment: @ThomasMueller  I need download current url to local  I creat a new file in js to download, But the chrome.downloads.download only can download via url.